# Serve external file download with php

Tags: php, youtube

I am trying to make a personal youtube video downloader using some snippets i found on the web. I get a url which is given by youtube which is only useful for the ip that requested it, so it is only working on localhost, because when its on a web server, download fails since the IP that requested the download link (web server one) is not the same as the client downloading it (me). My question is if there is some kind of way to:

a) Download video to web server and then download to my pc from there (not the best one)

b) Make youtube think that the webserver is downloading it when in real its me who is downloading the video using the web server.

URLs look like this:

http://o-o---preferred---ams03s12---v13---lscache7.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=TGDxfz8IZxI&sparams=cp%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&fexp=917000%2C903802%2C901425%2C920917%2C922401%2C920704%2C912806%2C924412%2C913558%2C912706&key=yt1&itag=18&ipbits=8&signature=4F0668E4E49852653FA995D28FECC455B552327D.3DEB3B58D1C5343B5EA03B7DA21355326EF29B7E&mv=m&sver=3&mt=1347451352&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&ms=au&gcr=es&expire=1347475934&ip=95.39.206.66&cp=U0hTTFRSU19ITkNOM19MTFdKOkVhV2otM1FhTXNj&id=2b4258153228ebc9

If you change the IP in that url to yours will still dont work, I already tried with that.

Comment: Can you use your server as a proxy somehow? I.e. Rather than having the entire video download onto your server, stream the raw bits to your server and then serve them straight out to your web client? I'm not sure how this would be achieved, but I'm sure it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

So trying to find a way similar to what ianhales said, this is what I finaly made: Its simple and probably the best way but it wors and helps me to fix another problem which was setting name of the  file with the name of the correspondient youtube video. Here is it:

```
$url=$_POST['url'];
$filename=$_POST['name'];

header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');

echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Where $url is the large url I posted on my question and $filename is the name of the video.

Maybe it will be helpful for someone so Im leaving it here.